# how to use a slot to update paint() in real time

Tags: c++, qt

I try to create some legend for my application which will be updated in real time. I've tried to use a slot to do it but I've gotten `No such slot legend::paint()`. 
Legend is updated only if I minimize and then maximize the window. Can anybody tell me how to properly use this slot to paint circles as representation of counter in legend?

legend.cpp:

```
#include "legend.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QTimer>
#include "player.h"

legend::legend(Player* player)
{
    this->player=player;
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(paint()));
    timer->start(1);
}

QRectF legend::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0,0,350,350);
}

QPainterPath legend::shape() const
{
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addRect(0, 0, 350, 350);
    return path;
}

void legend::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *)
{
    painter->setBrush(Qt::lightGray);
    painter->drawRect(0,0,350,350);


    painter->drawText(50,35,"COUNTER");
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(player->getCounter()>i){
            painter->setBrush(Qt::yellow);
            painter->drawEllipse((i+1)*30,50,20,20);}
        else {
            painter->setBrush(Qt::lightGray);
            painter->drawEllipse((i+1)*30,50,20,20);
        }
    }
}
```

legend.h:

```
#ifndef LEGEND_H
#define LEGEND_H

#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include "player.h"

class legend : public QGraphicsObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    legend(Player* player);
    QPainterPath shape() const;
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    QTimer *timer;
public slots:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *, QWidget *);
private:
    Player* player;
};

#endif // LEGEND_H
```

Comment: Use paint event and widget->update() There are a number of examples: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-painting.html

Comment: With graphicsitems, that'd be item->update(). Much more efficient than repainting the whole widget. You should call that only if the content actually changes though, and certainly not every ms (even if the painting would work that fast, 1000fps is waste and fat beyond what anyone can see)

Answer (score 1):

It's not your job to call `paint`. The `paint` method (not a slot!) is there for use by the `QGraphicsView` in rendering the scene.

What you should do instead is to inform the scene that the item has been updated. Connect the timer to a slot that invokes the `update` on the item:

```
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]{ update(); });
```

The views get informed by the scene about a need to repaint, and eventually invoke the `paint` method as necessary.

Your timer is *way* too quick. Change the timeout to `10` [ms] at the very least.

Another issue: you are polling the `Player` instance for its counter. Instead, the `Player` object should be broadcasting counter changes through a signal. Typically you'd declare the count as a `Q_PROPERTY`, and you can then have the `legend` item follow the property changes by listening to the property update signal.